# ImageView and EditText becomes dead after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have been trying to implement an animation on a relativeLayout. The animation works fine but after the animation is complete the edittext and the imageview inside the relative layout  stops responding to any kind of user activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_maincontroller_mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:background="@color/button_color" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_maincontroller_backImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_searchBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_maincontroller_backImage"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Before the animation the controls on the widgets work fine, the animation changes the parent relative layout from height 380 to 120 and after that the widgets become dead to any kind of user activity. I cannot control them. Can anyone please suggest an answer. Need it very urgently, have been stuck in it for hours.

The code for animating the layout is put below. I got it from a link and it worked as I wanted the animation to work but the widgets inside the layout became dead.

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {

private int startHeight;
private int deltaHeight; // distance between start and end height
private View view;

/**
 * constructor, do not forget to use the setParams(int, int) method before
 * starting the animation
 * @param v
 */
public ResizeAnimation (View v) {
    this.view = v;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

    view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (startHeight + deltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
    view.requestLayout();
}

/**
 * set the starting and ending height for the resize animation
 * starting height is usually the views current height, the end height is the height
 * we want to reach after the animation is completed
 * @param start height in pixels
 * @param end height in pixels
 */
public void setParams(int start, int end) {

    this.startHeight = start;
    deltaHeight = end - startHeight;
}

/**
 * set the duration for the hideshowanimation
 */
@Override
public void setDuration(long durationMillis) {
    super.setDuration(durationMillis);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
```

Then I call this class as follows:

```
ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(layout);
    a.setDuration(500);
a.setParams(oldHeight, newHeight);
    layout.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: Where is code how you animate it ?

Comment: I got it from some link I forgot about. Will it be helpful to put it in here?

Comment: Yes. It impossible to answer on your question without possibility to learn thoughts on a distance.

Comment: edited and added the animation code. would be a great help if you could guide me through this

Comment: Animation is an older Class you would want to go with Object Animator

Comment: @Divers can you help me out with the solution?

Comment: You still didn't show how you animate you layout.

Comment: @Divers I added the code that I am using to call the animation class